# Magento 2 undefined variable framework/App/ErrorHandler

Tags: magento2

facing this error undefined variable framework/App/ErrorHandler

> [2018-10-06 12:45:23] main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined variable: vls in /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php on line 46 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined variable: vls in /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/app/code/Sugarcode/Test/Model/Total/Fee.php on line 46 at /home/dukaania/public_html/testing2/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []

Please someone review my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Sugarcode\Test\Model\Total;




class Fee extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{

   /**
     * Collect grand total address amount
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this
     */


       protected $_coreSession;

    protected $quoteValidator = null; 

     protected $vls = null;


    public function __construct(\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteValidator $quoteValidator, \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $coreSession)
    {
        $this->quoteValidator = $quoteValidator;
           $this->_coreSession = $coreSession;
    }



       public function getValue()
{
     $this->_coreSession->start();
    return $this->_coreSession->getMyValue(); //Get value from customer session
}



  public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);




        global $total_cost;
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setValue($total_cost); //set value in customer session
$vluas= $customerSession->getValue();

$this->vls = $vluas[0].$vluas[1];


        $exist_amount = 0; //$quote->getFee(); 
        $fee = $this->vls; //Excellence_Fee_Model_Fee::getFee();
        $balance = $fee - $exist_amount;

        $total->setTotalAmount('fee', $balance);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('fee', $balance);

        $total->setFee($balance);
        $total->setBaseFee($balance);

        $total->setGrandTotal($total->getGrandTotal() + $balance);
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal($total->getBaseGrandTotal() + $balance);


        return $this;
    } 

    protected function clearValues(Address\Total $total)
    {
        $total->setTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('subtotal', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('tax', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setBaseTotalAmount('shipping_discount_tax_compensation', 0);
        $total->setSubtotalInclTax(0);
        $total->setBaseSubtotalInclTax(0);
    }
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    /**
     * Assign subtotal amount and label to address object
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param Address\Total $total
     * @return array
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
     */



    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {



       global $total_cost;
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
$customerSession->setValue($total_cost); //set value in customer session
$vluas= $customerSession->getValue();

$this->vls = $vluas[0].$vluas[1];
//print_r($vls);

        return [
            'code' => 'fee',
            'title' => 'Shipping Price',
            'value' => $this->vls
        ];

    }

    /**
     * Get Subtotal label
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getLabel()
    {
        return __('Fee');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

Add variable like this after this variable `protected $quoteValidator = null;`

```
protected $vls = null;
```

Then, use $vls variable like this : `$this->vls;`

For ex : **$this->vls = $vluas[0].$vluas[1];**

Comment: value show on first look or first time then it refresh to 0 :/

Comment: Did you replace from $vls to $this->vls in whole file code?

Comment: yes code is working on first when page load then it refresh to 0 value 
value not stay :/

Comment: Can you please update whole code after update variable ?

Comment: updated my code please have a look

Comment: I think you didn't get proper value in $vluas[0].$vluas[1]; please check that value or add here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84151/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-jhon-jhon-doe).

Comment: i text u in chat